# How to Track Screen in Flurry in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I am able to track the `events` and also able to track the `real time report`, but the problem is I am not able to track the `screen view`. 
I am using following code :-

```
Flurry.logEvent("Setting")        Flurry.logAllPageViewsForTarget(settingsTabButton)
```

Please provide the clear and simple step by step way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Official Flurry doc:

> [Track page views](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/technicalquickstart/ios/#track-page-views):
>
> ```
> Flurry.logAllPageViewsForTarget(navigationController)
> ```
>
> To enable Flurry Agent to automatically detect and log page view, pass
>   in an instance of UINavigationController or UITabBarController to
>   countPageViews. Flurry Agent will create a delegate on your object to
>   detect user interactions. Each detected user interaction will
>   automatically be logged as a page view. Each instance needs to only be
>   passed to Flurry Agent once. Multiple UINavigationController or
>   UITabBarController instances can be passed to Flurry agent.

Enabling this (disabled by default) by implementing above tracking metric will provide you following metrics for your app:

- Frequency distribution of page views per session
- Total page views over time
- Average page views per session

However, Flurry Analytics Page Views just counts the number of page views per session and are not specific to a particular screen in your application. So, tracking what pages are visited by user are via [Custom Events](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/events/ios/).

> [Page Views](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/pageviews/):
>   Page views in Flurry are tracked via Custom Events. You can tag a
>   Custom Event for every screen in your app and track the number of
>   visits and unique visitors, among other metrics.

Here's an example and writing this code in either `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` depends on the type of screen you want to track.

```
Flurry.logEvent("ScreenView_SettingsVC")
```

Comment: don't you think if i will track my event and page view both as LogEvent then i will be messed with identifying both.,i.e, i will not be able differentiate.

Comment: Well, I understand you. But then, you'd be treating page view as just another event and you'd be differentiating each type of events (if there are many) anyway. Personally, I find Flurry's interface not so friendly to differentiate.

Comment: So for commercial purpose what do you prefer

Comment: Already worked on google Analytics, amplitude looks nice, is it available in swift?

Comment: it's in objective-c only

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what pages in your app the user visits, It is better to create events for each of your screens and log it in `viewdidload`. The user paths report in the events section of your dashboard will then give you a clear path of how your users move around in your app.

Comment: don't you think if i will track my event and page view both as LogEvent then i will be messed with identifying both.,i.e, i will not be able differentiate.

Comment: You can use some naming convention for the screen load events. This naming convention will help you differentiate the screen load event with other events.